# Why didn't Naruto use Summoning Jutsu in Chuunin Exam?

Tags: naruto

They mention nothing about Summoning Jutsu in the exam and Naruto learned this jutsu before the exam.
Even if Gamabunta would not want to fight for Naruto, why didn't he at least try to use that jutsu?

Did I miss something? Did they actually say that Summoning was not allowed in the exam?

Comment: Naruto's Chuunin exam participation was shown in a non-canon episode where he  fought konohamaru. Eventually he used Sage mode and got disqualified from the chuunin exam. Other than that, I really don't think that it's not allowed to use any summoning jutsu during the chuunin exam.

Comment: @SahanDeSilva At what point is it specified that OP is talking about the filler Chuunin Exam and not the original Chuunin Exam arc? Judging by his question and context, it seems implied that he's referring to the original Chuunin Exam arc from the original series.

Comment: @JunKang Extremely sorry for my misunderstanding as I was confused with Genin and Chuunin exams. I had a confusion with regards to the original Chuunin exam arc as I remembered it as the genin exam. Anyway, I was just wondering.. Can't we consider Tenten's weapons summoning jutsu?

Comment: @SahanDeSilva No, Tenten's weapons are not considered summons, because she stores the weapons herself into her scrolls using a Sealing Jutsu. She may "summon" her weapons from her scrolls, but that's not entirely accurate. She's simply undoing her seals from the scrolls to "summon" her weapons. So calling her technique Summoning Jutsu would be innaccurate.

Comment: @JunKang Agreed. What about Orochimaru summoning his snakes? :D

Comment: @SahanDeSilva Orochimaru summoning his little snakes or turning his body to snake are not what I refer to. My question refers to Kuchiyose no Jutsu, Summoning Jutsu from contract with animal, mostly needing blood to perform the jutsu

Comment: @SahanDeSilva If you want to ask more questions, create a new question. This isn't what the comment section is for.

Comment: @Albert Even Orochimaru used summoning jutsu to summon snakes. He has blood contract with snakes just like Naruto having contracts with toads (though it isn't shown in any anime series as far as I can remember)

Comment: @SahanDeSilva for the big Snake (forgot her name, Manda?) yes it's Summoning. But when little snakes just went out out of his arm, or when his arm itself turned into snake, we don't know for sure if that's Summoning jutsu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, lets make a correction. Naruto learned the Summoning Jutsu, not before the exam, but only before the third round, prior to his fight with Neji. So he would have only had one opportunity to use the Jutsu during the exams, during his fight with Neji.

It is never EXPLICITLY stated, as far as I know, why Naruto didn't use Summoning Jutsu to summon Gamabunta during the fight, but let me give you a different perspective. Why would he want to summon Gamabunta in his fight against Neji?

1. He had a personal reason to fight Neji. He probably wanted to beat Neji on his own, 1v1, to prove his point to Neji. Probably wouldn't feel great to beat Neji because he had a giant frog step on him.
2. It would have been impractical. Gamabunta is HUGE. Gamabunta would probably have filled the entirety of the stadium they fought in. Even if Gamabunta did fight, he sure as hell wouldn't have been able to do so without destroying the stadium to hit a single tiny human target.
3. Like you mentioned, Gamabunta probably wouldn't have even wanted to fight for Naruto. The only reason he fought with Naruto against Gaara later is because he knew about the One Tail Beast and Gamakichi convinced him to.
4. Naruto had literally only used the technique once successfully in his training with Jiraiya, under threat of falling to his death. He probably didn't have confidence he could use it again. This is evidenced by the fact that in his fight with Gaara later, he only successfully summoned Gamabunta again because he was about to die, failing the first time by summoning Gamakichi. Naruto isn't able to reliably summon Gamabunta for quite a while in the series, summoning Gamakichi and Gamatatsu on multiple occasions.

Comment: Even during the first time he summoned Gamabunta, he had to borrow some chakra from the Kyubi. I'd guess that at that point, he neither had the control nor the chakra reserves (his own reserves) to do a proper summoning.

Comment: @TheGamer007 I thought of that as well, but decided to keep it out of my answer because, during his fight with Neji, Naruto does at one point tap into the Kyuubi's chakra. Which mean's he MAY have been able to use its chakra to successfully summon. So the lack of chakra doesn't really qualify as a reason for Naruto not to try.

Comment: Fair point. Well spotted